# File's Owner didn't received Action

Tags: iphone, objective-c

the ping1 and how1 below method didn't called from UIButton

so i was double checking it in xib what i am wrong.

but i can't found the problem.

to solve this only i can do is looking the xib and code

is there any know-how available to solve it?

something like insert some code when UIButton send event

anyone advice me it will be thankful

bonhyoung.

```
@interface ViewController : UIViewController

-(IBAction)ping1:(id)sender;
-(IBAction)how1:(id)sender;

@end

@implementation ViewController

-(IBAction)ping1:(id)sender
{
      // i put the break point in here
}

-(IBAction)how1:(id)sender
{
      // i put the break point in here
}

// some other code...
@end
```

Answer (score 1):

You should connect some IBOutlets and check in viewDidLoad that your connections are right (ie that your IBOutlets are not nil once the view is loaded).

Answer (score 0):

First make sure that the file owner's class is set to ViewController. This is in the IB pane, click on the File's Owner and select the 3rd tab on the right panel. It should say ViewController and not UIViewController.

Second make sure your actions are setup. Right click on the button, and make sure the Touch Up Inside is wired to the correct method.